# Active installs or total installs?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm confused about Google Play's install count.My app's total installs are above 5000 but active installs are around 2600.When i look at my app's Google Play page it shows 1000-5000 installs.Which one is considered for this part?Active installs or total installs?Or is there an update problem on Google Play on these days?

EDIT:
Problem solved.Here it is :http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an app store support issue, not programming an app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Play store shows the total amount of downloads. Your Console also shows, how many people are still active(have unistalled the app)

Comment: So why it's showing 1000-5000 instead of 5000-10000.This didn't changed since 2 days.

Comment: the play store statistics are incorrect most of the time - they just update it about twice a day, *but* sometimes it remains incorrect. But in this case not that wrong, because 1000-5000 is still correct. I think it will get changed to 5k - 10k when you'll hit about 6k downloads. I hope I could help.

Comment: I have 51 total installs (according to the dev console) but the play store is still showing `10-50`. It has been over three days... Please let me know! :)

Answer (score -1):

Total installs are the total number of people who have downloaded your app. Active installs is the total number of people who still have your app installed.

Comment: Okey i know that but why it's showing 1000-5000 instead of 5000-10000

Comment: TOTAL downloads. It isnt total + active or you would be counting active 2 times

Comment: @Quinma My app's total user installs are 5633 and active device installs are 2650.So it have to be 5000-10000 isn't it?

Comment: I have 51 total installs (according to the dev console) but the play store is still showing `10-50`. It has been over three days... Please let me know! :)